# Windows 7 set program as secure

Tags: windows-7, uac

I'm running Windows 7, and have a program that I run frequently that makes changes the OS (according to Windows 7). Every time I run it it asks me to confirm that this program is allowed to make the changes.

I would like to set this program so that it is always allowed to make the changes without me having to 'ok' it every time. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this without external programs as of now is to turn down UAC settings, you probably have it here:

[image]

You'll need to move it down a notch but that will affect all programs. If you would like it to work on a per-program basis, you can use [**Elevator**](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/16/ignore-uac-for-specific-programs.aspx) (previously called ElevateMe). Usage is explained further [here](http://dailyapps.net/2008/05/tip-quickly-disable-uac-for-specific-specific-programs/).

Comment: I'd prefer not to turn that down or use a third party program. Looks like I'll have to ok it every time.
Thanks for replying.